# Tableview won't scroll to top, hidden by scope bar when returning from view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a tableview with a searchbar with a scope.

The user searches, and search results appear perfectly in the tableview. When the user clicks on a cell in the tableview, they are taken to another view controller. But when I go back to the tableview from the view controller, I get issues.

The cell that I had previously selected becomes fairly centered on the screen, but it means that the tableview got positioned higher than it was before. The issue with this is that I can no longer scroll to the cells that were higher than the selected cell. Scrolling down works fine until the bottom. The top of tableview also gets hidden by my scope bar. Whats weird though, is that if I go to another tab and then return, the tableview fixes its position.

Here is what I do for my searchbar, incase the issues lies there.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    searchController.isActive = true
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .black
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Title1", "Title2", "Title3"]
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

    ...
}
```

So obviously, how can I avoid the tableview not letting me scroll up and the scope bar not covering the top of the tableview when I am returning from another view?